# Figure with caption within an itemize list not indenting correctly

Tags: graphics, floats, lists, indentation, itemize

I'm trying to put an image with a caption on it within an `itemize` environment (within another `itemize` environment). When I had the image with no caption, simply using `\includegraphics`, it indented to the same level as the other elements of the `itemize` list. However, when I wrapped it in a `figure` environment because I wanted a caption, it is indented to the left margin, completely sticking out of the list.

Here's what I've got:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Describing large-scale processor activity.

    \item To discuss digital systems of this scale and level of complexity
    we need a number of descriptive tools.

    \item For example:                                                 

    \begin{itemize}
        \item[a)] Circuit schematics highlight the circuit components and
        their connectivity.

        \begin{figure}[h]

            \includegraphics[width=10cm{assets/fig001.png}
            \caption{Transfer from R1 to R2 whenK1=1}
        \end{figure}
        \item[b)] Timing diagrams highlight the detailed time sequence of
        transfer between registers

        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{assets/fig002.png}

    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

I've tried `h`, `h!` and `H` in the `figure` positioning, but it stays exactly where it is.

TL;DR: How can I have the first image here indented like the second, but with a caption?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't use a floating environment (such as `figure`) if you want your image to appear in the exact position where you write it. You can use a `minipage` and, if a caption is required, the `\captionof` command (provided by the `capt-of` package or by the `caption` package).

In the following example I illustrate this approach; I also used the `enumitem package to customize the labels for the inner list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% demo option just for the example
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Describing large-scale processor activity.
    \item To discuss digital systems of this scale and level of complexity
    we need a number of descriptive tools.
    \item For example:                                                 
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
        \item Circuit schematics highlight the circuit components and
        their connectivity.\par
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=10cm]{assets/fig001.png}
            \captionof{figure}{Transfer from R1 to R2 whenK1=1}
        \end{minipage}
        \item Timing diagrams highlight the detailed time sequence of
        transfer between registers.\par
        \includegraphics[width=10cm]{assets/fig002.png}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using the solution of Gonzalo Medina, hypcap doesn't know where the actual figure is. The hyperlink in the List of Figures links to the caption directly instead of the top of the figure.

That's why this error is thrown:

> Package caption warning: The option 'hypca=true' will be ignored....

A better solution is using `\caption` in combination with `\captionsetup{type=figure}` above `\includegraphics`. That marks the beginning of the figure and allows the use of `\caption` outside of float environments.

An example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \listoffigures
    \newpage
    \chapter{List}
    \begin{itemize}
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \item
                \captionsetup{type=figure}
                \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{picture}
                \caption{text}      
        \end{minipage}
    \end{itemize}
    \newpage
    Add space.
\end{document}
```

I found the solution in [this](https://golatex.de/problem-mit-captionof-t2952.html) and [this](http://mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?65435-Seltsame-Warnung-bei-Hyperref-Hypercap) German source.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please translate your answer into english, that is the language used here!

Comment: I'm very sorry, I switched between English and German sources too many times and didn't realize I was writing in the English community :S