# Subfigure with caption within an itemize list not indenting correctly

Tags: lists, indentation, subfloats, itemize

To make it short, I have exactly the same problem as described here [Figure with caption within an itemize list not indenting correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54448/figure-with-caption-within-an-itemize-list-not-indenting-correctly) except, the fact that I am using the subfig package and the corresponding subfloat environment within the figure. Is there a way to get a correct indent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility, using a `minipage` of width `\linewidth` and a `figure` environment for which the `H` placement specifier (from the `float` package) has been used to suppress flotation, allowing the `figure` to be inside the `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% demo option just for the example
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
\item Second item with some additional text to span more than just one line.                      
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item And here we start a new list so the indentation increases before we include the images.\par
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \subfloat[A test subfigure inside some lists]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image1}}\hfill
    \subfloat[Another test subfigure inside some lists]{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image2}}
  \end{figure}
  \end{minipage}
  \item Some additional information.
  \end{enumerate}
\item Third item.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx! exactly what i was searching for! great explanation for beginners like me :)