# Subfigure using subcaption within enumerate is not indenting

Tags: indentation, enumerate, subcaption

I'm trying to put two images with the `subcaption` package side by side in an `enumerate` environement. This works fine, however the indent is not correct. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\item first item
\item second item
\item
    \begin{figure}[htb!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.40\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/fig1.eps}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.05\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.40\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/fig2.eps}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{(a) fig1 (b) fig2}
    \label{fig1and2}
    \end{figure}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Similar problems were discussed here:

[Subfigure with caption within an itemize list not indenting correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86518/subfigure-with-caption-within-an-itemize-list-not-indenting-correctly)
(I do not want to use the `subfig` package as it stands in conflict with `subcaption` package)

[Figure with caption within an itemize list not indenting correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54448/figure-with-caption-within-an-itemize-list-not-indenting-correctly)
(only one image is subject to the procedure)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: welcome to tex.se! help us to help you: extend your code snippet to full, small document which we can copy and compile.

Comment: Tank you for your input, I will do this right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the questions you've linked, the solution is to use the `minipage` environment (instead of the floating `figure` environment):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
\item first item
\item second item
\item~\\[-1em]\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/fig1.eps}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{fig1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{0.05\linewidth}
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/fig2.eps}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{fig2}
    \end{minipage}
    \captionof{figure}{(a) fig1 (b) fig2}
    \label{fig1and2}
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments:

- `figure` is a floating environment that will not respect margins set by the `enumerate` environment, even if you place it with `[h!]`. Use a `minipage` instead for user-defined positioning of things.
- Inside of `minipage`, the `\caption` command doesn't work. So use `\captionof` instead to make a user-defined caption without the need to be inside a floating environment. The first argument here gives the style of the caption to be used.
- To still be able to use the `\subcaption` command, you have to let it know what type of subcaption (i.e. table or figure) you want to have. Use the `\captionsetup` command for that.
- If you just put the `minipage` as an item, the label will be aligned with respect to the baseline of the graphics. I assume that you want to have the label at the top end of the graphics, so I inserted an empty line (`~`) and then a negative vertical space of the same size (`\\[-1em]`). The only effect of `~\\[1em]` is thus to have the item label at the top.

Comment: This works just fine! If you have some more time could you quickly explain what this command stands for:

`~\\[-1em]`

Comment: @muppethead I added some comments to the answer.