# Align figure inside a bulleted list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx

I'm using lyx, and I have a figure float inside a bulleted list.
I'd like the figure and especially the figure caption to align to the bulleted list, so that it's clear that the image belongs to the bullet.

Is there any way of doing it? I don't want the image itself to have a bullet, just alignment.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do directly in LyX: [image: screenshot]

- Wrap the figure float in a minipage box (Width: 100% linewidth, box vertical align: middle).
- Set the figure float position as "Here definitely" (`[H]` in LaTex). If you get errors about being `not in outer par mode`, then you forgot this step.
- Set the minipage on its own indented paragraph (notice the red vertical bar on the left).

Compared to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54449/11674, this solution has advantages:

- LaTeX-wise, the spacing above and below the figure is nicer.
- LyX-only: the command `\captionof` is not provided through the LyX interface (but you could still only use two LaTeX blocks containing `\captionof{` and `}` if you really need it).

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54449/11674), I added the following in a LaTeX block immediately after the item text in LyX:

```
\par\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics{myimage}                  
\captionof{figure}{My very very ... very long caption text}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: I take it the initial \par is to force the minipage below the bullet.